# Cuenta de facturación no configurada

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

estoy modificando un documento de firestore desde una función de la nube y en la consola de firebase recibo un mensaje que dice "Cuenta de facturación no configurada, no puede acceder a la red externa y las tarifas son muy limitadas, pero no hago llamadas a apis externos, ¿Debo activar la facturación?

```
 exports.setGeo = functions.firestore
.document('establecimiento/{id}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
const newData = snap.data();

if(newData.latitud == null || newData.longitud == null){
    let address =`${newData.direccion},${newData.nombremunicipio},${newData.nombredepartamento}`
    var options = {
        provider: 'google',
        language:'es',
        // Optional depending on the providers
        httpAdapter: 'https', // Default
        apiKey: 'apikey', // for Mapquest, OpenCage, Google Premier
        formatter: null         // 'gpx', 'string', ...
    };
    var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);
    geocoder.geocode({address: address, countryCode: 'CO'})
    .then(function(res) {
        //console.log("Resultado " , res);
        newData['id'] = context.params.id

        if(res != undefined && res != null && res.length > 0){
           let item = res[0];
           newData.latitud = item.latitude;
           newData.longitud = item.longitude;
        }
        else{ //pone colombia por defecto
            newData.latitud = -72.0000000;
            newData.longitud = 4.0000000;
        }
        //fecha actual en Unixtime
        let fechaRegistro = Number(Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000).toString());
        newData['fechaRegistro'] = fechaRegistro;
        console.log(newData.fechaRegistro);

        var docEstablecimiento = admin.firestore().collection('establecimiento').doc(context.params.id);
        docEstablecimiento.update(newData).then(function(res) {
            return true;
        })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error ",err);
    });
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no usas apis externas a Google no hace falta activar la facturacion de la cuenta. El mensaje aparece siempre que generamos funciones para Firebase, no te preocupes. Si deseas en un futuro usar apis como las de algun servicio como twitter u otro, ahi si deberias activar la facturacion ya que no te permiten hacer funciones sin abonar con apis externas.

Comment: Gracias, los proyectos sin facturación sólo están autorizados a hacer peticiones a Google, estoy haciendo peticiones a firestore no entiendo por qué me muestra el aviso y no me permite hacer la modificación del documento en firestore

Comment: lo del aviso no es lo importante, debe ser el codigo de la funcion que no esta funcionando

Comment: Si es importante al hacer el llamado a firestore `docEstablecimiento.update(newData)` se presenta el mensaje y no se actualiza el documento